# Run SQL TADOQuery against earlier saved TADODataSet in Delphi

Tags: delphi, ado

I use a table valued function in SQL server which builds a table of about 25 columns and several thousands of rows. This takes about 5..10 seconds each time the function is called. And currently I call it about 90+ times in relation to 1 project.
I aim to call this function only once, and save it's output locally. Currently I use an SQLite file created locally, but since the original query is TADOQuery I'd like to make use of SaveToFile

```
procedure x;
var
  Query: TADOQuery;
  DS: TADODataSet;
begin
  // Query gets created and receives it's data from another function
  ...
  Query.SaveToFile(TPath.GetTempPath + 'locally cached ADOQuery');
  CloseQuery(Query);
  
  // opening the dataset and reading it from the saved file works
  DS := TADODataSet.Create(nil);
  DS.LoadFromFile(TPath.GetTempPath + 'locally cached ADOQuery');
  DS.Open;
  // at this point I can use the DS as I could use the Query before my modifications
end;
```

How could I make queries against this dataset? I tried adding these before `DS.Open;` without any effect:

```
  DS.CommandType := cmdText;
  DS.CommandText := 'select column1';
```

I'm not sure what the `from table` clause should be. According to [embarcadero](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_TADODataSet) this should be possible, but I cannot seem to inspect the dataset as explained below:

> Like a query-type dataset, TADODataSet lets you specify a single SQL command that is executed when you open the dataset. To use it in this way, set the CommandType property to cmdText and the CommandText property to the SQL command you want to execute. At design time, you can double-click on the CommandText property in the Object Inspector to use the Command Text editor for help in constructing the SQL command. TADODataSet supports query-type tasks such as...

Even the simple SQL like `select 5` is ignored and I still get the 20+ columns and many thousands of rows, just like in the original query.

Comment: AFAIK, with the possible exception of ODBC, Ado components rely on the back-end server for their ability to retrieve records using SQL,  A locally-saved Ado dataset has no back-end server and so no SQL querying capability.

Comment: A retrieved dataset from "saved to file" will always have the entire dataset. To hide part of the content you can use filters : you set a filter condition on the Filter property, and set Filtered to True.

Comment: Filter sounds promising, but since I cannot use random SQL like the above mentioned `select 5` or `select 'some text I want'` I'm sticking to SQLite

Comment: You could also save the output to a session scope temporary table (#tablename) in SQL server and populate/repopulate it when you connect or want possibly updated values in it. Then reference that instead of the table valued function in your queries.